A question about Borel measures in Folland
This is from Folland real analysis page 33. My question is that $\mathcal{A}$ isn't equal to any of the $\mathcal{E_j}$, It doesn't just include left-open, but also intervals of the form $(a,
 \infty)$ and not just that but also all finite disjoint unions of them which may even not be intervals at all. So what am I missing?

The building blocks for our theory will be the left-open, right-closed
intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ - that is, sets of the form $(a, b]$ or $(a,
 \infty)$ or $\varnothing$, where $-\infty \leq a<b<\infty$. In this
section we shall refer to such sets as $h$-intervals ( $h$ for
"half-open"). Clearly the intersection of two h -intervals is an h
-interval, and the complement of an h-interval is an h-interval or the disjoint union of two h-intervals. By Proposition 1.7, the collection
$\mathcal{A}$ of finite disjoint unions of h-intervals is an algebra,
and by Proposition 1.2, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by
$\mathcal{A}$ is $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$.
1.2 Proposition. $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{E}}$ is generated by each of the following:
a. the open intervals: $\mathcal{E}_1=\{(a, b): a<b\}$,
b. the closed intervals: $\mathcal{E}_2=\{[a, b]: a<b\}$,
c. the half-open intervals: $\mathcal{E}_3=\{(a, b]: a<b\}$ or
$\mathcal{E}_4=\{[a, b): a<b\}$,
d. the open rays: $\mathcal{E}_5=\{(a, \infty): a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ or
$\mathcal{E}_6=\{(-\infty, a): a \in \mathbb{R}\}$,
e. the closed rays: $\mathcal{E}_7=\{[a, \infty): a \in \mathbb{R}\}$
or $\mathcal{E}_8=\{(-\infty, a]: a \in \mathbb{R}\}$.


Clearly any set in $\mathcal{A}$ is a Borel set, hence $\mathcal{E}_j\subset\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{B}$, and so the $\sigma$-algebras generated by each of the above must be included in the other. Yet $\sigma(\mathcal{E}_j)=\mathcal{B}$, showing that $\mathcal{A}$ generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

@Davood Karimi Yes, $\mathcal{A}$  does not contain contain any $\mathcal{E}{i}$ for any $i\notin {3,5}$ and that is not claimed any where. All it says is the sigma algebra generated by the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ equals the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal{E}{i}$, for each $i$, equals the Borel sigma algebra. These sigma algebras are all equal and are the Borel sigma algebra. The algebra $\mathcal{A}$ itself is generated by the $h-$intervals. Notice that the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$ is in fact equal to the sigma algebra generated by the $h-$intervals

If $\scr U, V$ are two collections of sets and $\mathscr U \subset \sigma(\mathscr V)$ and $\mathscr V \subset \sigma(\mathscr U)$, then $\sigma(\mathscr U) = \sigma(\mathscr V)$. It is easy enough to see that each the various types of intervals can be obtained by a countable intersection or union of each of the other types of intervals - with some complementation for constructing finite intervals from intersections of the infinite ones.
